# Entity superclass implicitly created?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I have an Entity, Customer, which extends its superclass Entity, User. User has an Inheritance type of JOINED and contains a primary key column.

**If I create and persist an instance of Customer will it implicitly create and persist the corresponding instance of User?** If not, how would I create and persist an instance of Customer properly?

Comment: are you using hibernate.?

Comment: No I am not using hibernate. Just JPA.

Comment: Can you provide some code examples/ annotations used in entity and let us know if it is working or not?

Comment: Joined inheritance means there are two tables representing the subclass.  So when you persist a Customer, JPA will insert a row into all parent tables that together form a Customer instance.

Comment: @Chris so the answer to my question is: yes it will create and persist the instance of the superclass as well?

Comment: Not really, as you are calling it multiple instances there is no superclass 'instance'.  A Customer is both a Customer and User - there is only one instance.  At the database level, your customer instance will map to two tables, and both will have a row to support this customer instance.  I wanted to be clear as some posters believe you can change java types by switching flags etc.

Comment: I see. I understand how the table structure works so perhaps I should have worded it differently. I just wanted to verify that the persistence provider would handle the mapping. And it seems it does.

Answer (score 0):

If all mappings are correct  then this should work
please also check `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn (annotation based)` is added in the child class

If you need more information and help search for `One Table Per Subclass Inheritance`, because you are using this i guess.

Comment: "If no PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation is specified for a subclass in the JOINED mapping strategy, the foreign key columns are assumed to have the same names as the primary key columns of the primary table of the superclass" [Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/PrimaryKeyJoinColumn.html) Therefore, the @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn is not needed.